# People born from the year 2020 onwards have superpowers, how does society cope?

Tags: super-powers

Let us say that anyone born on or after January 1st 2020, will develop some type of superpower by the time they reach puberty. These powers can vary in their scope from physical mutations a la Clayface, to plain magical abilities like most X-men. The extent of what each individual can do is effectively unpredictable.

How does society cope going forward? Is there any hope for governments across the world to maintain order? Or is humanity doomed to enter an era of anarchy?

Comment: This question is far too broad, and you need to focus it on one aspect. I know you've been around the SE block a few times, but accept this gentle admonishment to review the [tour] and [help]: we like focused, single point questions. Like "...how does the health sector of the economy cope?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If everyone has superpowers. No one really has superpowers

Superpowers are relative. If everyone can run faster than a bullet then you have no speedsters, you need to to move your baseline and get faster bullets, if everyone has super strength then there is no super strength, your world just has weak objects.

A super villain can beat one superman. But can he beat a million justice league characters? I doubt it.

2030-2040 will be incredibly unstable as these powers manifest. You'll get teenage super villains and teenage  super heros fighting, and all the powers will not be evenly matched, but soon after you'll get young adults recruited into super police and countries with super military, eventually when us normies die out your society will be full of approximately equal people again.

The transition will obviously has some violence, as youth will fight and cause much collateral damage, but you'll also get youth fighting for their normal loved ones, and fighting for their own beliefs and moral code. Youll get peavekeeper youth fighting aggressive youth to keep the peace and earn respect. For every school shooter / recently single / suicidal youth wanting to bring the place down, youll have 10 super powered youth who just want a finish their classes in peace. You'll lose some cities to the fighting, every high school will probably have structural damage, but  human civilisation will survive.

Comment: Love the Incredibles quote!

Comment: IMHO you are missing the main implication of the scenario. All juveniles have superpowers. All adults don't. Eventually everything may work out just as you said. But a lot (like civilization go bye-bye) can change in the meantime.

Comment: "If everyone has cell phones and penicillin, then nobody has cell phones and penicillin."  Seems like a silly statement.  Superpowers are not relative.  Sure, nobody would have a humongous advantage over each other, but there is more to life than competition.  In cases where humans cooperate, they would be advantaged to be able to achieve more than they could without powers.  And let's not forget that not everyone has superpowers.  The elderly would become 2nd-class citizens with no control over their destinies, and no recourse to atrocities.

Comment: Hmmm these are all great points you guys are making... I think I might soon post my own answer in response to this...

Comment: @cowlinator that is a silly statement. It only works with relative nouns. If everyone has "a great cell phone" then nobody has "a great cell phone", everyone only has a normal cell phone. No recourse at all? They couldn't use propaganda against other young open minds and get them to fight on their behalf? Propaganda aside - Have mortals really never defeated a super villain without a superhero in all of fiction?

Comment: How about an army of supervillains?  And of course they could use propaganda.  Would it work?  Maybe.  Or maybe they would become slaves.  When you require people to stand up for you, you are powerless and at their mercy.